# run time error for rotation of array

Tags: c, arrays

The following code is supposed to rotate the array A by B positions.

So, for example,

A : [1 2 3 4 5 6]
B : 1

The output :

[2 3 4 5 6 1]

my code is

(im just a beginner hence such a complicated code)

```
int* rotateArray(int* A, int n1, int B, int *len)
{
   int *ret = (int *)malloc(n1 * sizeof(int));
   *len = n1;
   int i=0;
   int J=0;
   int t=0;
   t=(i+B)%n1;
   if((i+B)>=n1)
   {
      for(i=t;i<n1;i++)
      {
         ret[J]=A[i];
         J++;

      }
      for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
      {
         ret[J]=A[i];
         J++;

      }
      return ret;
   }
   else
   {
      J=0;
      for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) 
      {
         if((i+B)<n1)
         {
            ret[i] = A[i + B];
         }
         else
         {
            ret[i]=A[J];
            J++;
         }
      }
      return ret;
   }
}
```

i am getting run time error
Runtime Error. Your submission stopped because of a runtime error. ex: division by zero, array index out of bounds, uncaught exception You can try testing your code with custom input and try putting debug statements in your code.

*** Error in `./solution': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000009640a0 ***

Aborted

Your submission encountered runtime error for the following input:

A : [ 14, 5, 14, 34, 42, 63, 17, 25, 39, 61, 97, 55, 33, 96, 62, 32, 98, 77, 35 ]

B : 56

The expected output for this testcase is:

35 14 5 14 34 42 63 17 25 39 61 97 55 33 96 62 32 98 77

i have no clue why !
all my test cases are correct

Comment: Close-voter: Why is it unclear? I think it lacks [mcve], as call to `free()`  is missing altogether.

Comment: Not my DV: but variables named `A`, `n1`, `B`, `J`, `t` with no calling context make it hard to follow the code. In a month's time you won't remember what they mean either, so please use meaningful names!

Comment: An array is not a matrix

Answer (score 0):

You are looping too much in your second for loop and writing past the end of your allocated output array (because you are always incrementing J). So change

```
   if((i+B)>=n1)
   {
      for(i=t;i<n1;i++)
      {
         ret[J]=A[i];
         J++;

      }
      for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
      {
         ret[J]=A[i];
         J++;

      }
      return ret;
   }
```

to be:

```
   if((i+B)>=n1)
   {
      for(i=t;i<n1;i++)
      {
         ret[J]=A[i];
         J++;

      }
      for(i=0;i<t;i++) // ichanged the stop condition here from i<n1 to i<t
      {
         ret[J]=A[i];
         J++;

      }
      return ret;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems longer than necessary. This should be enough:

```
int * rotate(const int * A, int steps, int len)
{
    int *ret = malloc(steps * sizeof *ret);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        int pos = i-steps;
        if(pos < 0)
            pos+=len;
        ret[pos]=A[i];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I removed one parameter, since all you did with it was to assign it to the value of another parameter.